# SQLite with MVC Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a database in memory and run a query with .NET Core 2.1 framework. To do this I have installed a package called `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` and then tried to do the following:

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
connection.Execute("Some Create Table Query");
```

And my code will crash with the following error:

> You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  If you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init().

I've done a lot of digging to find a solution and one of them suggested calling this:

```
SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());
```

This produces me a new error:

> 'Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

I am really lost at this point how to accomplish this. All I want to do is create an in-memory database so I can run some queries for purposes of unit testing.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I am not using EF6, I am using Dapper and also I am using SQL Server in my actual project. I wanted to plug in Sqlite in unit tests so I can also test my queries.

I have a feeling I am using wrong packages, but looking around there are so many and I can't find any clear documentation on how to use Sqlite with MVC Core projects.

Comment: I was going to suggest DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(string), but you can't use DatabaseFacade.ExecuteSqlCommand() with in memory database, because it is not a relational database!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the [`SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green/) package to your project.

```
dotnet add package SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green
```

At that point, the following program ([inspired by this](https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/tree/master/samples/InMemorySample)) works:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
        connection.Open();

        var createCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
        createCommand.CommandText =
        @"
            CREATE TABLE data (
                value TEXT
            )
        ";

        createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This is the test that I ran locally.

```
cd C:/temp
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core
dotnet add package SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green
//
// paste the above program into Program.cs, then...
//
dotnet run
```

**What is bundle_green?** `bundle_green` is one of the Sqlite "bundle packages", which are expressly designed to ease cross-platform development. Here is a description from [the official repository](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw#bundles):

> These packages automatically bring in the right dependencies for each platform. They also provide a single Init() call that is the same for all platforms... SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green is a bundle that uses e_sqlite3 everywhere except iOS, where the system-provided SQLite is used.

Comment: is `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` mvc core friendly? As in, it won't be windows dependent. Trying to keep my framework on core and not mix it up with .net.

Comment: Adding Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core was enough without manually adding those others, at least of .NET core 2.2 SDK.